# For Each loop only deleting some of the cells meeting the criteria

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I wrote a sub for deleting all rows where the cell in column A contains text that is all uppercase.

When i run it, it only removes some of the rows, but not all of them. It is like it is not looping through the whole range.

```
Sub changeIt()

Dim iHolder As String, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A19")

For Each Cell In rng

    iHolder = UCase(Cell)

        If StrComp(Cell, iHolder, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then

            Cell.EntireRow.Delete

        End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replace `For Each` with `For ... Next` with `Step -1`.**

In your case, if you delete the row, rows below it move one position upwards. Therefore your `ForEach` skips some rows, because its internal pointer always moves one position forward - whether there was deletion or not. You should be able to easily discover the problem simulating it with pencil and paper.

**The easiest solution is to iterate rows from bottom to top using `For ... Next`**

```vb
For i = LastRowNumber To FirstRowNumber Step -1
    ...
    If StrComp(...) = 0 Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If        
    ...
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to maximize performance and delete rows in one statement only

so you could go like follows

```
Sub changeIt()

Dim unionRng As Range, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A19")
Set unionRng = Range("B1") '"dummy" range, to prevent Union method from failing the first time it's called

For Each cell In rng
    If StrComp(cell, UCase(cell), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, cell)
Next cell
If unionRng.Count > 1 Then Intersect(unionRng, rng).EntireRow.Delete ' Intersect method removes the "dummy" range from the one whose rows are to be deleted

End Sub
```

I enclose a "formula" approach too, which doesn't iterate through cells and uses a "helper" column (the one at the right of the range to scan), which therefore must be "free"

```
Option Explicit

Sub changeIt2()    
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:A19")    
With rng.Offset(, 1)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(exact(Upper(RC[-1]),RC[-1]),"""",1)"
    .value = .value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    .Clear
End With

End Sub
```